Thumbnail caching
BRIEFLY:
How to make a script?
The script opens all subfolders of a given folder and scrolls the entire folder.
Thumbnails are cached for all images in these folders.
FOR WHAT:
Thumbnails of all pictures are displayed immediately without waiting.
Users need to open folders with pictures often and a lot.
WHAT I TRIED:

Manually - too long.
This needs to be done on different PCs.
Every day after work.
Better every hour.
Because pictures are added regularly during the day and in very large quantities in random folders according to date and topic.

I found the script.
However, it is for win xp,
there were hidden cache files in every folder,
and in win 10 the cache became centralized in 1 place for all folders.
So this script won't work.
https://www.xyplorer.com/xyfc/viewtopic.php?t=3981



Solution
https://superuser.com/questions/116396/automatically-generate-thumbnails-for-all-subfolders-of-a-directory-in-windows-7
